# The purchasing email isn't mine

Tags: pokemon-go

How do I change the purchasing email to my own Google accounts so that I can spend my money.

Answer (score 1):

From Android Enthusiasts:
[How do I change my email address on Play Store as the one I have is no longer in use](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46870/how-do-i-change-my-email-address-on-play-store-as-the-one-i-have-is-no-longer-in):

> Go to settings->accounts->add account->and add another Google account with the new email. Then go into the play store and there will be your email with a drop down arrow. Tap it and select the new email.

Pokémon Go Android will always lead you to the Account which is logged into PlayStore when you intend to purchase the In-Game curreny "Gold Coins".

Comment: Thank you for responding. It does say my email in the play store as well as when I log into the pokemon go app. Problem is when I go to make a purchase it someone else's Emil and money that shows up and I am unable to correct it to use a different email. I added Google play money and I can see that it's there thru the play store but once in the app it just doesn't exist. It automatically brings up my son's email address with his play money he has added. I accidentally took his money but attempting to correct the problem just at a loss.

Comment: @Mel2lyssa But you can select both of the e-Mails in PlayStore?

Comment: Yes. I have multiple accounts in my phone but only use 1 for gaming or emailing. The other ones are my kids that I monitor for school only.

Comment: Strange behavior, dont have an Android Phone right now to check it here. Removing your children's account temporarily is probably also no option, but might bring you better results.

Comment: I will try that and see if it helps. Thank you for your help.